# Инициализация указателя

Tags: c++

Объясните пожалуйста новичку:
Часто видел в коде профессионалов и толковых программистов как они объявляли указатель в классе, но инициализировали его в конструкторе. Почему так? Пример:

```
#include "A_Class.h"
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass();
    A_Class *obj;
}

MyClass::MyClass()
{
    obj = new MyClass();
}
```

И вот сейчас, когда писал на Qt получил ошибку и случайно её исправил. У меня был инициализирован указатель в классе, а не конструкторе. Инициализировал его в конструкторе - исправил ошибку.

Так вот, почему именно так нужно действовать? Неужели есть разница?

Comment: Поясните как это "в классе".

Answer (score 4):

Дело в том, что инициализация нестатических полей класса прямо в теле класса стала доступна только начиная со стандарта C++11. Такая инициализация полезна, когда исходное значение или аргументы конструктора заранее известны. Но для инициализации нестатического поля класса может понадобится аргумент, который передается в качестве параметра в конструктор:

```
MyClass::MyClass(int x)
{
    obj = new MyClass(x);
}
```

Но даже при инициализации непосредственно в теле конструктора следует по возможности использовать список инициализации (более того, это единственный способ для инициализации в конструкторе нестатических полей с `const` квалификатором):

```
MyClass::MyClass(int x)
: obj{new MyClass{x}}
{

}
```